# Open URL short cuts in new window

Tags: java, gwt, java-io

I have a some URL short cuts files in my web page and I want to open particular URL in new browser window tab on clicking it.
(currently I can achieve a functionality to download file on clicking).

like,

`facebook shortcut.url`

`google shortcut.url`

I am working on GWT and has only client side access of that page.

So,
1) is it posible to read a content of this file? so i can read a particular url from file and open it in new window (only from client side).

Comment: URL shortcut files in a webpage? Isn't that a hyperlink? `<a>`

Comment: No this not a hyperlink, server give me a list of an objects which contains a different properties of that link like shortcut file path, its name etc.

Comment: Ahh ok, Well you could try using a bit of JSNI and possibly something like this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNvK9/)